# How to obtain conversationId in nuxeo plugin

Tags: java, seam, nuxeo

I'm working on a Nuxeo plugin which implements an operation. So I'm using `@Operation`, `@OperationMethod` and `@Context` annotations. The purpose of plugin is to get LiveEdit link, and the problem is I can't obtain conversationId which is needed for building a nxedit: URL. Nuxeo source code uses
`Manager.instance().getCurrentConversationId()`
but I can't obtain Manager instance in my plugin either. And it seems impossible to inject Manager instance via @Context, it returns just null value.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at `Seam.InitContext` and `Seam.RunOperation` operations?

Both do a call to `org.nuxeo.ecm.automation.seam.operations.SeamOperationFilter.handleBeforeRun(OperationContext, String)` and `org.nuxeo.ecm.automation.seam.operations.SeamOperationFilter.initializeSeamContext(OperationContext, String, CoreSession)`. The conversationId should then be available:

```
ConversationPropagation.instance().setConversationId(conversationId);
Manager.instance().restoreConversation();
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Both methods requires a `conversationId` as String parameter, and my problem is I can't obtain it. They using `conversationId = (String) context.get("conversationId");` but it seems that there is no such key in plugin context.

Comment: You can still pass null. But if you run your operation in a chain after one of the above operations, then the seam context should have been initialized.

Comment: When I'm trying to call `Seam.InitContext` operation I get `Can not init Seam context: no HttpServletRequest was found`. I'm calling it like this:   `OperationContext operationContext = new OperationContext(session);  
  operationContext.setInput(doc);  
  OperationChain chain = new OperationChain("chain");  
  chain.add("Seam.InitContext");  
  AutomationService automationService = Framework.getService(AutomationService.class);  
  automationService.run(operationContext, chain);`